# Cannot access key values in an object with React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, reactjs

Working on a project in React using a MongoDB database.  I am trying to access key values in objects, but I get an error when I try to access them.  I can access the objects themselves, but as soon as I use dot notation, React crashes and says TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined. The only instance I can get the data is when I console log in my fetchData() function before it goes through componentDidMount.

```
class TimelineContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      lifeEvents: [],
      currentUser: auth.currentUser
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData()
  }
  fetchData(){
    LifeEventModel.all().then( (res) => {
      this.setState ({
        lifeEvents: res.lifeEvents,
        uid: res.lifeEvents.uid,
        currentUser: auth.currentUser
      })
      console.log(this.state.lifeEvents[0].title)
    })
  }
```

[Link](https://timeline--app.herokuapp.com/lifeevents) to database backend hosted on heroku. [Link](https://github.com/jamesnsummers/project-02/tree/james-dev-4) to my github repo.

```
render(){
console.log(this.state.lifeEvents[0].title)
console.log(this.state.lifeEvents);
return (
  <div className='timelineContainer'>
    {
      (this.state.currentUser != null) ?
      <div>
        <CreateLifeEventForm
          currentUser= {this.state.currentUser}
          onCreateLifeEvent={this.createLifeEvent.bind(this)} />
        <Timeline
          currentUser= {this.state.currentUser}
          lifeEvents={this.state.lifeEvents}
          onDeleteLifeEvent={this.deleteLifeEvent.bind(this)}
          onUpdateLifeEvent={this.updateLifeEvent.bind(this)}
        />
      </div> :
      <section className="col-md-4 col-sm-12 add-event">Log in to add a life event</section>
    }
  </div>
)
```

}
}

render method above. First console log throws the error. Second one does not.

Comment: When it crashes, what error does it give?

Comment: show the error message and can you show the render method?

Comment: Have you console logged the `res` when fetched from DB ?

Comment: Sorry should have added - TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(this.state.lifeEvents);` in the render method?

Comment: The output of `console.log(this.state.lifeEvents);` is my array of objects.

Comment: The console.log in the first code snippet will not work because `setState` is **not synchronous**. You have no guarantee that state will be immediately updated after calling `setState`. Please take a detailed read: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that since you are not fetching your data asynchronously, the initial result `this.state.lifeEvents` will be null. so you have to first check for the null value until react updates the state and re-renders.
try this out:

```
renderView = () => {
  return (this.state.lifeEvents === null)? <div>Loading...</div> :   
        (<div>
          <CreateLifeEventForm
          currentUser= {this.state.currentUser}
          onCreateLifeEvent={this.createLifeEvent.bind(this)} />
        <Timeline
          currentUser= {this.state.currentUser}
          lifeEvents={this.state.lifeEvents}
          onDeleteLifeEvent={this.deleteLifeEvent.bind(this)}
          onUpdateLifeEvent={this.updateLifeEvent.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>)
};

render(){
   return (
   <div className='timelineContainer'>
    {
      (this.state.currentUser != null) ? this.renderView() :
      <section className="col-md-4 col-sm-12 add-event">Log in to add a life event</section>
    }
    </div>
  )
}
```